# Problem with connecting an Xbox One to a monitor

Tags: xbox-one, monitor

I have an Xbox One which I use with a TV. I now want to use my large monitor instead. It's a LG W3000H which works fine with my pc.

I connected the Xbox to the monitor using a HDMI to DVI cable, but the monitor only gave me a black screen.

To check whether the problem was related to the monitor, I connected another monitor with same cable (a Syncmaster SA450) and it works right away with no issues.

Can anyone direct me to what the issue could be with there not appearing any image on my monitor?

Comment: Could be a problem with the DVI port. Do you have an HDMI-HDMI cable to connect your Xbox to your screen?

Comment: When running HDMI to DVI, you shouldn't incur any loss of data. Hence, I doubt it is related to the conversion. I do think @Nolonar is on the right track with his question.

Comment: hi thanks Nolonar and Eric, my Screen has No HDMI port only DVI port, can a port work while connecting to PC but not to Xbox?, screen works fine if I connect it to PC. I have a new HDMI to DVI cable, can it make a difference if I buy a HDMI to DVI convertor t use the original Xbox cable?(I wouldn't things so but what is your opinion?)

Comment: If the same port works with your PC, then it should work with your Xbox too. I did some research on [the specifications of your screen](https://productz.com/en/lg-w3000h/p/GZDb1), and everything looks fine. If you have an Xbox One X and your TV is 4k, it's possible your Xbox is sending a 4k signal that your LG screen can't work with (normally your screen should say something like "signal out of range"). In that case, you should use your TV to configure your Xbox to use Full HD (1920x1080) before connecting it to the LG screen. Beyond that, I have honestly no idea what else you could try.

Comment: thank for your reply, no signal out of range message, my monitor when not connected to a source has a yellow light next to the ON button and when connected and works with PC it turns blue, strange thing is that its also blue when connected to xbox just screen stays black?????? I have an old tv I am using its not 4k, and I have an xbox one not x, I will try to configure xbox with another tv to full HD, I think only options on xbox under video are 720 and 1080 is 1080 full HD? or is there another setting? thanks

Comment: Yes, Full HD is 1080. 720 is "just" HD. Both should work with your LG screen, though I'm afraid the problem might be something else entirely.